# tlbimpとはどう使うものですか?

Tags: c#

まずはこの記事を見ていただきたい。http://elicon.blog57.fc2.com/blog-entry-186.html
ビデオからフレームを抜き出すコードが書かれている。いままで探したもの中でも手順が簡単そうですが、

> tlbimpを使って、C:\Windows\System32\qedit.dllを.NETから使えるDLLを作って参照に追加

という部分がわかりません。
誰かこの文章の意味と参照に追加するまでの手順を教えてくれませんか？

Comment: [Tlbimp.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/tt0cf3sx(v=vs.110).aspx) , [Tlbimp.exe を使用してプライマリ相互運用機能アセンブリを生成する](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/tw4zwhbe(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tlbimp.exe` というのは VisualStudio に付属するツールで、COMタイプライブラリに含まれる型定義を.NET用に変換するものです。今回の場合 `qedit.dll` がそのタイプライブラリになっているので、これを.NETから利用するために `tlbimp.exe` で変換を行う、ということです。

スタートメニューから「VS2012の開発者コマンドプロンプト」などを起動すればそのコマンドにもパスが通った状態になるので、

```
cd /d d:\myproject
tlbimp c:\windows\system32\qedit.dll
```

とすれば `DexterLib.dll` が出力されます。これを VisualStudio の「参照の追加」で指定します。

[Tlbimp.exe (タイプ ライブラリ インポーター)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx)

または、 VisualStudio の「参照の追加」でCOMタイプライブラリ（例えば `qedit.dll` ）をいきなり指定すると、同じように変換したうえで参照に追加してくれます。

ただ・・・ご質問に書かれているサイトでは次のようにも書かれていて、

> 参照の追加でCOMから、『Dexter 1.0 Type Library』を追加。

このタイプライブラリの実体が `qedit.dll` です。なので、どちらか一方だけを行えばいいのでは・・・。

Comment: なるほど、よく分かりました。ありがとうございます。